# OpenCV - Dynamically find HSV ranges for color

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

When given an image such as this:

[image]

And not knowing the color of the object in the image, I would like to be able to automatically find the best H, S and V ranges to threshold the object itself, in order to get a result such as this:

[image]

In this example, I manually found the values and thresholded the image using cv::inRange.
The output I'm looking for, are the best H, S and V ranges (min and max value each, total of 6 integer values) to threshold the given object in the image, without knowing in advance what color the object is. I need to use these values later on in my code.
Keypoints to remember: 
- All given images will be of the same size.
- All given images will have the same dark background.
- All the objects I'll put in the images will be of full color.

I can brute force over all possible permutations of the 6 HSV ranges values, threshold each one and find a clever way to figure out when the best blob was found (blob size maybe?). That seems like a very cumbersome, long and highly ineffective solution though.

What would be good way to approach this? I did some research, and found that OpenCV has some machine learning capabilities, but I need to have the actual 6 values at the end of the process, and not just a thresholded image.

Comment: You might be interested in [Otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method). You can pass the flag `CV_THRESH_OTSU` to `cv::threshold()` to enable it.

Comment: Thanks. That could actually be handy for something else I'm trying to do. Here, though, I do need to have the 6 H,S and V values at the end of the process, and I can't get those using Otsu's method. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I'm also interested because I'm working on an overloaded RPI3 and having image segmentation in realtime seems to be an impossible task right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small 2 layer neural network for the task of dynamic HSV masking.
steps:

1. create/generate ground truth annotations for image and its HSV range for the required object
2. design a small neural network with at least 1 conv layer and 1 fcn layer.
3. Input : Mask of the image after applying the HSV range from ground truth( mxn)
4. Output : mxn mask of the image in binary
5. post processing : multiply the mask with the original image to get the required object highligted